# How to make types narrowing works inside switch(root.type.code)?

Tags: typescript, type-narrowing

Narrowing works only if need to check key inside root. If exist nesting of target key then it doesn't work. Why does it work like that?

[Ts Playground with example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsFMCdtASwM4QJ4AdqoHYENZYB7Ad0RwHNQZ4BYAKHPDgDM8BjBAQQwwBsEAbwahR6LAC5QAchawAronDSA3CLH4AttCnJwschTX0xoPBR2gc8zQCM4xgL4MGTVhwQAFIuDzgioMImYuCYltIAbtAUquqiWpZ6BpTGpuaW1nYODM70rjjMsGycoADK%20ngk9oRogXHi4dWwaLHB8XjauvqGTi707EQ4emaEUlyEeGgAPDz8CAA%20oN6%20-qCL5bCVTWgAfKAAvKAA2vWCoZIycorKADRWHeEJ0nfpUgCMAEyON6fn4VExO4JKTSJ4vCzvL4-NqBP4g7bPe6dGRPb4MAC6xgYBFgADpNHgMAAKJTQTQHPZBUzIMjgdiQUAk5iaXF-ACUdRhpnYeGQCFkCiU0gk9VMpng4HksBwSGZqTFogAJtA2PI%20OARVyFaAJVKZdY%20Hx5aJco42Vj6CBQIqiNgcNJwKASERYABrUCAPg3ACi7fTcRQ8oFmAjenNMcMCA2VIKuQscxqRiW6KXqrysNmqvTyjAK7hKyz8RBDVJCYSkgkj-2i0jj9WBoCSPRTELTWVgmfyhWKCA2WzgzSL9XD5aIUZkCJrMLrDeT9FyDAGQ0dOLeYwm0yD0BDi3z-i3ZQqVT7aDee0OJxhZ1LEZH4Rjym%20CZBYLMzc%20aIvQ4rIIB1aBDyfDyIqmb7QqYl4XMOo7SOOf7IqCgHvpifTLvihJMmSFKhmINJKPSjKkiyfy4hWHLFgqPJ8pcgrKJq2pirq0qymS8amMqqrqrRdFiAx%20pqka9SmuaQA)

Desired behavior:
TS understand type in second example as specific type not tuple

Comment: It's working for me! I debug your code and show alert in switch case and I saw the alert

Comment: Item in second example is `union` instead of `Apple1`

Comment: I don't know what exactly  you want. please generate error in your playground link and give it to me in comment

Comment: There is no error. Item in second example is still union type `Apple1 | Potato1 | ...` but I'm waiting another behavior like in first example - `item` is `Apple1`

Comment: use as Apple1[] to convert it to array of `Apple1`.

Comment: The `map` function never change the `type` of  array. It's just projection

Comment: This isn't answer on my question. I found the reason:
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758
Typescript just can't do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript just can't do it yet

[Nested Tagged Unions #18758](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18758)